# Is there a way to create 'Cell Styles' in xlsxwriter which can thereafter be used by the Excel file user?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a script which automates the creation of an Excel template for multiple users - and a large part of the template is the inclusion of our Cell Styles. These are used to identify inputs, calculations, etc. and it would be great if I could include these within the code.

At this stage, I understand `xlsxwriter` enables the formatting of cells, however I can't seem to find any documentation enabling the editing of Excel cell styles (think alt+ HJ).

I've read through the developer's documentation and haven't found anything which could help.

Potentially, should a write-through in VBA resolve this?

Example of the equivalent coding of cell style `H0 Header 0`:

```
cell_format_H0 = workbook.add_format({
    'font_name': 'Arial',
    'font_size': '22',
    'font_color': 'black',
    'bold': True,
    'bottom': True,
    'bottom_color': 'black'
})
```

Comment: you need to `getCellStyle` first ... then just modify it ... and `setCellStyle` with the modified version ... or you mean the style is not editable in excel ? (I find this hard to believe that you cannot simply select the cell and edit the style) ... (Im pretty sure the styles are not globally available, it is attached directly to each cell)

Comment: Cell styles aren't supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks John - I'll keep exploring other options.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am specifically referring to the storable Cell Styles within Excel that can be used for consistent formatting by the user. It's a part of our methodology for financial models which I would like to include within the setup of the output file.

Failing this, I'm guessing a simple VBA code executed after the creation of the file will suffice, but I'm trying to package everything together into the Python code first.